# The Mellin transform as a mapping from a Hardy space to a weighted space

Tags: reference-request, special-functions, mellin-transform, hardy-spaces

As far as I know, the following fact must be published somewhere, and I would like to find a reference.

The Mellin transform is defined by $f\mapsto\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^\infty f(x)x^{s-1}\,dx$. The classical fact is that it is a unitary operator from $L^2(0, \infty)$ to the unweighted $L^2$-space on the *critical line* $\{\Re s=\frac12\}$. Also it is a unitary operator from the Hardy space $H^2$ on the half-plane $\{\Re z>0\}$ to the weighted $L^2$-space on the critical line with weight $e^{\pi t}+e^{-\pi t}$ if we write $s=\frac12+it$ for $s$ on the critical line; this is the fact I am interested in. To apply the Mellin transform to a function $f\in H^2$, one takes the above integral on $(0, \infty)$; the formula can be applied to functions that decrease exponentially near zero and infinity, such functions form a dense set.

Comment: [The same at MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/424590/the-mellin-transform-as-a-mapping-from-a-hardy-space-to-a-weighted-space).